# Efficient way to get a part of a CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, csv

Lets say I need all data from row 50 to row 100 from a CSV file.
I was wondering if there is a more efficient way from looping through every row and check if the current row is between 50 and 100?
Right now I have a simple code which works fine, but if I want a range towards the end of the CSV file then it becomes a bit slow.

```
$start = 200000; 
$end = 200050;
$handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
$i = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
if(($start <= $i) && ($i <= $end)) {
    echo $data[0] . ' - ' . $data[1] . ' - ' . $data[2] . ' - ' . $data[3];
    echo '<br />';
}
elseif($i > $end) {
    break;
}
$i++;
}

fclose($handle);
```

Is there a way maybe to use an offset or something similar so I don't have to loop through every single line?

**UPDATE:**
The solution needs to work with larger files. Memory is limited, so reading in the whole file into the memory won't work.

Comment: Question: What exactly are you planning to do with that CSV data once you've loaded it? I ask because the most common reason for loading CSV data is to save it into a database. If that's what you're doing and if you're using MySQL, you can use a `LOAD DATA INFILE` query to get MySQL to load the CSV data directly without PHP having to do any of the work. It'll be a lot less work for you, and it will be a *lot* quicker to execute.

Comment: Basically CRUD operations. I have to use CSV. Database is not an option in this case.

Comment: Database not an option at all? Wow. Not even SQLite or one of the NoSQL engines? Just how much data are you expecting to have here, because even if you solve the memory problem, your performance is going to really suck if you aren't allowed to have any kind of indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$filename = "data.csv";

// Read the file into an array
$lines = file($filename);

// Output the 50th line
echo $lines[49];
```

So, using your example you could easily output the 50 lines you require using:

```
for($i=0; $i<50; $i++) {
    echo $lines[$i + 50] . '<br/>;
}
```

Check out the documentation on PHP's [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function

Comment: Thanks, but this would mean that I have to read the whole file into the memory, which in case of a larger file will case issues. Sorry I forgot to add this information to my post. I will update it.

Comment: In that case, that's a different question entirely. You can use ```fseek``` to specify the offset but you'd need to know that by total byte size. This could be calculated easily, if each line is of the exact same length.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will read large file line by line

```
<?php    
    function readLine ($linenum,$fh) {
                $line = fgets ($fh, 4096);
                $pos = -1;
                $i = 0;

                while (!feof($fh) && $i<($linenum-1)) {
                    $char = fgetc($fh);
                    if ($char != "\n" && $char != "\r") {
                        fseek($fh, $pos, SEEK_SET);
                        $pos ++;
                    }
                    else $i ++; 
                }
                $line = fgets($fh);
                return $line;
            } //readLine()
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you've got a CSV data file, potentially containing large numbers of records, and you need to be able to dive into to to do direct reads from further down the file without having to read the rest of the file first.

Yes, this can be done -- you will need to use [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) to move the file position pointer:

```
$handle = fopen(....);
....
$startAt = 10000;
$success = fseek($handle, $startAt);
$data = fgets($fp, 1000);  //read the next 1000 bytes of the file after the starting position.
```

However, this will not be as easy for you as that example makes it look.

Your CSV data almost certainly has variable-length lines. This means you can't just tell it to jump to a particular byte position and know what line that is. You will have to have a way to know the specific starting byte position for the record you want to jump to. And if any records are edited, those byte position you remembered previously will become incorrect.

If you're just using this for pagination, then you could get away with remembering the byte positions for the previous pages and calculating the start of the next page by current pos +1.

But jumping to arbitrary records around the file -- eg random access, given a record number -- will be virtually impossible unless you keep an up-to-date index of the byte positions of where all the line endings are. (if you do this, then you'll have effectively implemented a basic ISAM database)

The real question is why (per your comment) a database is out of the question. Okay, so maybe you can't install mySQL, but a simple SQLite database can be created and managed entirely from within your PHP program, and only creates a single file on disk; in that respect it's almost as convenient as a CSV, and certainly easier to work with if you've got more than a trivial amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ////insert and view screen////////////


        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

                <!-- jQuery library -->
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

                <title>Demo</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="formme">

                    <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['submit']) == "Submit") {

                        $inputPost = $_POST;
                        $name = isset($inputPost['fname']) ? $inputPost['fname'] : "";
                        $email = isset($inputPost['lname']) ? $inputPost['lname'] : "";
                        $subject = isset($inputPost['telNo']) ? $inputPost['telNo'] : "";
                        $message = "";

                        $file_open = fopen("contact_data.csv", "a");
                        $no_rows = count(file("contact_data.csv"));
                        if ($no_rows > 1) {
                            $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
                        }
                        $form_data = array(
                            'sr_no' => $no_rows,
                            'name' => $name,
                            'email' => $email,
                            'subject' => $subject,
                            'message' => $message
                        );
                        fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
                    }
                    //fclose($form_data);



                    $row = 1;
                    if (($handle = fopen("contact_data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

                        echo '<table border="1" style="width:60%;" ><tr><td>Id</td><td>UserName</td><td>Email</td><td>message</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>';

                        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
                            $num = count($data);

                            $datainfo = array_filter($data);
                            if(!empty($datainfo)){
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>' . $data[0] . '</td><td>' . $data[1] . '</td><td>' . $data[2] . '</td><td>' . $data[3] . '</td><td><a href="editcsvdetails.php?id=' . $data[0] . '" >edit</a></td><td><a href="deletecsvdetails.php?id=' . $data[0] . '" >delete</a></td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }

                            $row++;
                        }

                        echo '</tbody></table>';
                        fclose($handle);
                    }


                    ?>


                    <form name="csvForm"  id="csvForm" method="post">


                        <div class="form-1">
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <label for="fname" class="fname">First name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ph-1">
                                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Your name.." vale="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-2">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <label for="lname" class="lname">Last name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ph-2">
                                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Your last name.." vale="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-3">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <label for="telNo" class="tel">Phone number</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ph-3">
                                <input type="tel" id="telNo" name="telNo" placeholder="Your phone number..." vale="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="btn">
                            <!--<button class="formSubmit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>-->
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </body>
            <script>
               /* function editcsv($id)
                {
                    var id = $id;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/practise/csv/editcsv.php",
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {id: id},
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            alert(data.msg);

                        }

                    });
                    // alert($id);
                }
                function deletecsv()
                {

                }
        */
            </script>

        </html>


    > /////edit and//////////////////


    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) == "Submit")
    {
        $inputPost = $_POST;
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = isset($inputPost['fname']) ? $inputPost['fname'] : "";
        $lname = isset($inputPost['lname']) ? $inputPost['lname'] : "";
        $telephone = isset($inputPost['telNo']) ? $inputPost['telNo'] : "";

        $i = 0;
        $newdata = [];
        $handle = fopen("contact_data.csv", "r");

        // READ CSV
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            if ($data[0] == $id) {
                $newdata[$i][] = $id;
                $newdata[$i][] = $name;
                $newdata[$i][] = $lname;
                $newdata[$i][] = $telephone;

                $i++;
                continue;
            }
            $newdata[$i][] = $data[0];
            $newdata[$i][] = $data[1];
            $newdata[$i][] = $data[2];
            $newdata[$i][] = $data[3];
            $i++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
        // EXPORT CSV
        $fp = fopen("contact_data.csv", 'w');
        foreach ($newdata as $rows) {
            fputcsv($fp, $rows);
        }
        fclose($fp); 
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <!-- jQuery library -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

            <title>Demo</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="formme">
                <?php 
                if(isset($_GET['id']))
                {
                    $value = $_GET['id']; // Wert dieser Spalte

                    if (($handle = fopen("contact_data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
                            /*$datainfo = array_filter($data);
                            if(!empty($datainfo)){


                            }*/
                            if ($data[0] == $value) { 

                            ?>
                            <form name="csvForm"  id="csvForm" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id"  value="<?php echo $data[0]; ?>">
                                <div class="form-1">
                                    <div class="col-1">
                                        <label for="fname" class="fname">First name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ph-1">
                                        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Your name.." value="<?php echo $data[1]; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-2">
                                    <div class="col-2">
                                        <label for="lname" class="lname">Last name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ph-2">
                                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Your last name.." value="<?php echo $data[2]; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-3">
                                    <div class="col-3">
                                        <label for="telNo" class="tel">Phone number</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ph-3">
                                        <input type="tel" id="telNo" name="telNo" placeholder="Your phone number..." value="<?php echo $data[3]; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="btn">
                                    <!--<button class="formSubmit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>-->
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <?php }
                         }

                    }
                }
                ?>

            </div>
        </body>
        </html>


> //////Delete csv record/////


<?php 
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($id) {
    $file_handle = fopen("contact_data.csv", "w+");
    $myCsv = array();
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);    
        if ($id != $line_of_text[0]) {
            fputcsv($file_handle, $line_of_text);
        }
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
     ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href='index.php';
    </script>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
for($i=49; $i<100;$i++) {
    echo $lines[$i].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.